# React input value to array not working when using onClick

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array that I'd like to add a new name from the user's input.  In my component I have:

```
<div>
  <h4>Add A Player</h4>
  <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Enter a new name"
    value={this.state.newPlayerName}
  />
  <button onClick={this.handleAddPlayer}>
     Press to Add Player
  </button>
</div>
```

Which works with this function except for the name:

```
handleAddPlayer = e => {
  const players = this.state.players.slice(0);
  players.push({
    name: '',
    id: getRandomInt(20, 55)
  });
  this.setState({
    players: players,
    newPlayerName: e.target.value
  });
};
```

I'm trying to get when a user inputs a name and submits it, it updates in the function which updates the array (if this makes sense, apologies as this is still pretty new to me).

In my state I have:

```
this.state = {
  id: players.id,
  totalScore: 0,
  countInfo: [],
  evilName: '',
  color: '#6E68C5',
  scoreColor: '#74D8FF',
  fontAwe: 'score-icon',
  incrementcolor: '',
  scoreNameColor: 'white',
  glow: '',
  buttonStyle: 'count-button-start',
  newPlayerName: '',
  players
};
```

I'm not sure how to get the input to pass the name (or string) to the array, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you added bound input-updating handler to the wrong element! You currently have it attached to a button, you have to have it attached to the input! Add an `onChange` handler to your input to update the value every time you change the input:

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="Enter a new name"
  value={this.state.newPlayerName}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

Then create a new method that handles the change:

```
handleChange = e => {
  this.setState({
    newPlayerName: e.target.value
  });
}
```

This will let React control the input, and set the input value in state so you can use it when adding a new player. Then, set up the handler to add a new player on click. Instead of slicing, pushing, the resetting, just use array spread syntax:

```
handleAddPlayer = e => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    players: [...prevState.players, {
      name: this.state.newPlayerName
      id: getRandomInt(20, 55)
    }]
  }));
}
```

This will set `players` to the previous state's `players` property *plus* the new player object with a `name` that's the input's value and a random `id`.